# Mongoose - Restrict the fields on referenced model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have `users` model that can hold multiple `notifications`. In the `NotificationSchema` the `notifier` holds users ID and it references the `users` model. When I execute the following query :

```
User.find().populate('notifications.notifier').exec(function(err,users){
  //users[0].notifications[0].notifier    
  //I am getting all fields from the referenced user   
  //I don't want the whole document but some fields only 
});
```

How can someone Limit / Restrict the fields that should be available while referencing to some model.

**Here is the `users` model**

```
var NotificationSchema =new Schema({
    notifier : {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'users'},
    //How could I say :
    //notifier : {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'users', fields:['_id', 'name']}
    //because I know what fields do I need from referenced model for this Schema.

   __SOME__
   __OTHER__
   __FIELDS__
});

var UsersSchema = new Schema({
    name : {given:String, middle:String, family:String}
    email:String,
    password:String,
    notifications : [NotificationSchema]
});

var Users = mongoose.model('users', UsersSchema);
```

BTW, I do not have separate `model` for `NotificationSchema`.

If this feature is not available out of the box how could I implement it manually. Am I missing some docs? Please let me know the `robust` way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found it in mongoose docs**

I found the answer in **Field Selection** Section of [the documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

```
User.find().populate('notifications.notifier', '_id name').exec(function(err, users) {
 //users[0].notifications[0].notifier           ^^^^^^^^^ HOW FUNNY
 //Yes I am getting '_id' and 'name' fileds only
});
```